# how to calculate Average-Case complexity time by using worst-case and best-case complexity time?

Tags: data-structures, asymptotics

For example let's say that we know that the worst-case running time is o(n) and the best-case is o(1). how can i get the average-case running time using the given big Ohs?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You don't have enough information. Consider the following program:

1. Let $n = |x|$.
2. If $x = 0^n$ then terminate.
3. If $x = 1^n$ then run a loop for $n$ steps.
4. Otherwise run a loop for $f(n)$ steps.

Here $f(n)$ is any function satisfying $f(n) = O(n)$. In an appropriate computation model, the best-case complexity is $O(1)$, the worst-case complexity is $O(n)$, and the average-case complexity is roughly $f(n)$.

Comment: so you are saying that by just having worst and best case running time i can not get average running time.right?

Comment: @gandalf Exactly. Just like knowing the biggest and smallest of a set of numbers tells you nothing about the average (except that it can't be smaller than the smallest or bigger than the biggest).